# MySQL filtering query

Tags: mysql

i am looking to write a query that filters the output according to the number of occurences of in a column. e.g (a room number `1` occurs 5 times in the column `room number`. if the number of occurences is between `0-5` the room number `5` should be among the output, if not it shouldn't be an output)

this is my query:

```
$query = 'SELECT room_no, COUNT(room_no) as count FROM banabas_sr GROUP BY room_no HAVING count BETWEEN 0 AND 6';
```

but it doesn't output anything even when all the room's in the table occur only once.

when i click this button:

```
<input type="submit" name="check" value="CHECK AVALIBILITY" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored" id="magic" />
```

it is supposed to pass this info:

```
<div class="labels-input room">
                   <!--Hostel-->
                   <?php
                   if ($row['gender'] == 'Male') {
                     $option1 = 'Banabas';
                     $option2 = 'Banabas Annex';
                   }
                   else {
                     $option1 = 'Faith';
                     $option2 = 'Faith Annex';
                   }?>
                   <div class="labas"><div class="form-group">
                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                       <select class="form-control" name="hostel" required>
                         <option></option>
                         <option><?php echo $option1; ?></option>
                         <option><?php echo $option2; ?></option>
                       </select>
                     </div>
                   </div></div>
                   <!--Hostel-->

                   <!--Room Type-->
                   <div class="labas"><div class="form-group">
                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                       <select class="form-control" name="r_type" required>
                         <option></option>
                         <option>Executive</option>
                         <option>Standard</option>
                       </select>
                     </div>
                   </div></div>
                   <!--Room Type-->
```

to this php script:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['check'])) {
    $hostel = $_POST['hostel'];
    $type = $_POST['r_type'];
    if ($type == 'Standard') {
      $_POST['r_type'] = 'SR';
    }
    else {
      $_POST['r_type'] = 'ER';
    }
    if ($hostel == 'Banabas' && $type == 'SR') {
      $query = 'SELECT room_no, COUNT(room_no) as count FROM banabas_sr GROUP BY room_no HAVING count(room_no) BETWEEN 0 AND 6';
      $ex = mysql_query($query);
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ex)) {
        echo $msg = "<option value='" . $row['room_no'] . "'>" . $row['room_no'] . "</option>";
      }
    }
  }
 ?>
```

to populate this div:

```
<div class="labas"><div class="form-group">
                     <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                       <select class="form-control" name="av_rooms">
                         <?php echo $msg; ?>
                       </select>
                     </div>
                   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$query = 'SELECT room_no, COUNT(room_no) as count FROM banabas_sr GROUP BY room_no HAVING count(room_no) BETWEEN 0 AND 6';
```

The having clause after the group by reffers to aggregate functions on the columns , you can use max,min,avg and ETC but you have to calculate it inside the having clasue, not use the column from the select part.

Comment: Using the column alias in the `having` clause in MySQL is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT()` is always going to be at least one for this query (when `room_no` is not `NULL`).  You need another list of room numbers find the unmatched rooms.  Let me assume `rooms` table:

```
SELECT r.room_no, COUNT(room_no) as num
FROM rooms r LEFT JOIN
     banabas_sr b
     ON r.room_no = b.room_no
GROUP BY r.room_no
HAVING num BETWEEN 0 AND 6;
```

I don't like using `count` as the name of a column because it is also the name of a function.

Comment: i am trying to avoid making the database more complex than it already is as i am a beginner in php/mysql. is creating a new table really the only way to go about this?

Comment: If you have an entity identified by `room_no`, you should probably have a table describing them.  In fact, this would seem necessary because there appear to be rooms of interest that are not in `banabas_sr`.

Comment: all rooms of intrest that Standard are in `banabas_sr`

Comment: i.ve added more of my code to the question as i'm now unsure if it's the sql query or my script